# Ошибка в виде вопросов

Tags: php, openserver

Хочу переименовать файл через метод `rename()`, но выдает максимально непонятную ошибку в виде знаков вопроса. Может у кого была такая проблема?

Сам код:

```
foreach($files as $file) {
    if ($file == "." or $file == "..") continue;
    $f = stat($dir.$file);
    if ($f['size'] > 20480 or is_numeric(basename($file)[0])) {
      unlink($dir.$file);
      continue;
    }
    else {
      $name = basename($file);
      $newName = "+".$name;
      rename($name, $newName);
    }
```

[image: screen]

Comment: a) явно чужой код, кодировка которого "потерялась" или не в UTF-8 б) приложите сам код

Comment: Изменил, добавил кусок кода

Comment: <meta charset="UTF-8">
тоже есть, но вначале всего

Comment: Вставьте  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: Вставил. Ничего не поменялось) Остальные ошибки нормально выдает, это именно с этой какая-то проблема

Comment: А какая кодировка у index.php и у тех самых файлов текстовых? Что за названия файлов - какой язык? Как минимум, топорно попытайтесь вывести через echo сами $dir, $file. Никто же не знает, что у вас там за директория, что за файлы.

Comment: установить в списке предпочитаемых браузером языков на первое место анлгийский не пробовали?

Comment: Все файлы нормально открывает, записывать в файлы тоже без проблем можно. Проблема такая только с этим методом почему-то. Может вы знаете как можно переименовать файл по-другому? Мне просто нужно добавить "+" в начало названия каждого файла

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, да, пробовал

Comment: Содержимое файлов - обычный текст, добавленный с помощью lorem

Comment: Еще я хотел попробовать посмотреть ошибку через try catch, но у меня так тоже не получается)

Answer (score 0):

Вопросики вместо букв появляются, когда браузер выводит текст в utf8 кодировке, но спотыкается о непонятные последовательности бит. Непонятны они браузеру потому, что они в другой кодировке (в вашем случае скорее всего win1251). При этом английские буквы универсально кодируются в любой кодировке, а вот, например, символы кириллицы кодируются по-разному. Поэтому английские слова в варнинге не исказились, а русские выглядят как набор вопросов.

Сообщение об ошибке вероятно зависит от операционной системы и ваш виндоуз пытается говорить с вами по-русски. Чтобы понять его, надо смотреть на это сообщение в win1251.

Впрочем, проблему видно и без чтения варнинга. Обратите внимание, что для других функций (stat и unlink) вы указываете директорию, а для rename не указываете. Как rename поймёт в какой директории вы хотите переименовать файл?